# How can I enlarge the font of tooltips?

Tags: faces, fonts, tooltip

I want to enlarge the text in tooltips displayed via https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PosTip . What can I do?

Comment: Does it have to be using PosTip? If not, see [Show Key](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowKey) for one way to do it.

Comment: @Drew  company-quickhelp uses pos-tip, and I don't know enough elisp to change it ...